# Is it possible to share a register between threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, x86, arm, mips

I know that when the OS/Hardware switch between the execution of different threads it manage the store/restore the context of each thread, however I do not know many of the details. My question is: are there any register that I can use to share information between threads? In x86? mips? arm? etc,. linux? windows?

Any suggestion on how this can be done is highly apreciated.

Comment: What is your question?  Can this be done for **ANY** OS or is this possible with some currently functioning **OS**?  The criteria are contrary; you wish to isolate threads by definition.  The registers in question will need the compiler to get involved.  Ie, the compiler can not touch those registers.  As SuperCat notes, it is hypothetically possible.  It is not something that would be present in Posix threads unless it is a special register that a compiler will not normally use.

Comment: If I could write my own OS them I could do the task switch basically the way I want. I'm looking for a currently functioning OS. If it runs only on x86, arm or mips is irrelevant.

Comment: Would you like it to be running on a multicore machine as well? Then how can that work? From a certain level of abstraction this question is meaningless. When you dig down below that level of abstraction, then you are asking a very broad question which makes the question meaningless again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems reasonable at first glance.  Other people have tried to answer the question directly.  First we have two fairly nebulous concepts,

1. Threads
2. Registers

If you talk to **Ada** folks, they will freak out at the lack of definition of a *linux* or *posix* threads.  They like something more like *Java's* green threads with very deterministic scheduling.  I think you mean threads that are fast for the processor, like *posix* threads.

The 2<sup>nd</sup> issue is what is a *register*?  To most people they are limited to 8,16 or 32 registers that are hard coded in the CPU's instruction set.  There are often *second class* registers that can be accessed by other means.  Mainly they are are amazingly fast.

### The inverse

The inverse of your question is quite common.  How to set a register to a *different* value for each thread.  The general purpose registers are use by the compiler and the **ABI** of the compiler is intimately familiar to the *OS context switch* code.  What may not be clear is that things like the *upper bits* of a **stack** register may be constant every time a thread runs; but are different for each thread.  That is to say that each thread has its own stack.

With ARM Linux, a special *co-processor* register is used to implement [thread local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459692/linuxs-thread-local-storage-implementation).  The *co-processor* register is slower to access than a **general purpose** register, but it is still quite fast.  That takes us to the difference between a process and a thread.

### Endemic to threads

A process has a completely different memory layout.  Ie, the **mmu** page tables switch for different processes.  For a thread, the register set may be different, but all of regular memory is shared between threads.  For this reason, there is lots of *mutexes* when you do thread programming.

Now, consider a CPU cache.  It is ultra-fast memory just like a **general purpose** register.  The only difference is the amount of instructions it takes to address it.

### Answer

All of the OS's and CPUs already have this!  Each thread shares memory and that memory is **cached**.  Loading a *global variable* in two threads from *cache* is near as fast as register access.  As the *thread register* you propose can only hold a pointer, you would need to de-reference it to access some larger entity.  Loading a *global variable* will be nearly as fast and the compiler is free to put this in any register it likes.  It is also possible for the compiler to use these registers in routines that don't need this access.  So even, if there was an OS that reserved a **general purpose** register to be the **same** between threads, it would only be faster for a *very small* set of applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are some processor architectures where certain registers are not stored during context switch. From memory, 29K has some registers like that, which are essentially just global variables - `gr112 .. gr115` from looking at the web. Now, this is a machine that has 192 physical registers, so it's not really a surprise it can afford sacrificing a few for this sort of purpose.

I know for a fact that x86 and x86-64 use "all registers", as does ARM. From what I can gather, MIPS also doesn't have any registers "reserved for the user". This applies to both Windows and Linux operating systems.

For any processor with a small number of registers (less or equal to 32), I would say that "wasting" registers are globals just to hold some value that some other thread/process may want to read is a waste of resource - generic code will run faster if that register is used as a general purpose register available for the compiler.

Comment: Sometimes on the ARM, it may be helpful to have a register dedicated to holding the address of a structure which in turn holds frequently-accessed items.  A normal access to an arbitrary static variable would require two load instructions--one to get its address, and one to read the variable itself--but many fields of a structure whose address is known to be in a register will be accessible using a single load instruction.

Comment: Yes, but you have to access that very often (or be required to access it very quickly) to take that trade-off. ARM only has 16 registers, and some are already taken such as PC (r15) and SP (r14?).

Comment: If one's program is small enough that one can practically put nearly all of one's static variables into a single structure, and if it uses primarily static data, such a structure can easily get used enough to be a big win not just in speed but code size as well.  The original Macintosh did something much like that by reserving A5 as a pointer to an area holding up to 32K of applicaton static data.  That allowed any application static variable within that area to be accessed using the (A5+ofs16) addressing mode.  Too bad there's no similar convention for the ARM.

Comment: Obviously, this depends on what the code is doing to a very large extent. Compilers are often quite clever, and if you have a lot of data in a (global) structure, it may well be able to use the same trick within a function - so, load the base-address of the struct in a register, and then use base+offset to get to it. Either way, major OS's tend to not do this, probably because it doesn't actually pay off...

Comment: When the compiler generates code for method `Foo` which uses structure `Bar` and is callable by external code, it can't assume that external code is going to have put the address of `Bar` in some register unless `Bar` is an explicit parameter.  I think the big reason today's systems don't do such things is that it's only possible to take advantage of such features if the size of the "special" static data area is known to be small.  Code which assumes something will be within the "special" area won't link if the thing won't fit.

Comment: There are such things on the ARM; You can instruct `gcc` to reserve a register.  This is all that the *MRI* compiler did for the 68k systems which used an `aX` register.  There is nothing to stop someone from doing this today.  There is also *thread local storage*, which does something similar for threads; but backwards to the idea of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing all the code that will go in a system, you may dedicate registers to whatever purpose you want, subject to the limitation that any register which is dedicated to a particular function will be unusable for any other purpose.  There are some very specialized situations where this may be worth doing; these generally entail, bizarre as it may seem, programs that are very simple but need to run very fast.  Some compilers like gcc can facilitate such usage by allowing a programmer to specify particular registers that the code it generates should not use for any purpose unless explicitly requested.  In general, because the efficiency of compiled code will be reduced by restricting the number of registers the compiler can use, it will be more efficient to simply use statically-defined memory locations to exchange information between threads.  While memory locations cannot be accessed as quickly as registers, one can reserve many of them for various purposes without affecting the compiler's ability to optimize register usage.

The one situation I've seen on the ARM where using a dedicated register was helpful was a situation where a significant plurality of methods needed to share a common static data structure.  Specifying that a certain register should always be assumed to hold a pointer to that data structure, and that code must never modify it, eliminates the need for code to load the address of that structure before accessing items therein.  If you want to share information among threads, that might be a useful approach, since accessing an arbitrary static location generally requires a PC-relative load to fetch the address followed by a load of the actual data; having a dedicated register would eliminate one of the loads.