# How to access errno after clone (or: How to set errno location)

Tags: linux, clone, errno

Per traditional POSIX, `errno` is simply an integer lvalue, which works perfectly well with `fork`, but oviously doesn't work nearly as well with threads. As per pthreads, `errno` is a thread-local integer lvalue. Under Linux/NTPL, as an implementation detail, errno is some "macro that expands to a function returning an integer lvalue".

On my Debian system, this seems to be `*__errno_location ()`, on some other systems I've seen things like `&(gettib()->errnum`.

**TL;DR**
Assuming I've used `clone` to create a thread, can I just call `errno` and expect that it will work, or do I have to do some special rain dance? For example, do I need to read some special field in the thread information block, or some special TLS value, or, do I get to set the address of the thread-local variable where the glibc stores the error values somehow? Something like `__set_errno_location()` maybe?

Or, will it "just work" as it is?

Inevitably, someone will be tempted to reply "simply use phtreads" -- please don't. I do not want to use pthreads. I want `clone`. I do not want any of the ill-advised functionality of pthreads, and I do not want to deal with any of its quirks, nor do I want the overhead to implement those quirks. I recognize that much of the crud in pthreads comes from the fact that it has to work (and, surprisingly, it *successfully* works) amongst others for some completely broken systems that are nearly three decades old, but that doesn't mean that it is necessarily a good thing for everyone and every situation. Portability is not of any concern in this case.
All I want in this particular situation is fire up another process running in the same address space as the parent, synchronization via a simple lock (say, a futex), and `write` working properly (which means I *also* have to be able to read `errno` correctly). As little overhead as possible, no other functionality or special behavior needed or even desired.

Comment: Don't use `clone` (or `futex`) syscall; it is essentially reserved to those *implementing* thread libraries. Just use [pthread](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads) (without `clone` or `futex` ...)

Comment: OK, thank you for the hint. I am familiar with pthread, and as stated, I am explicitly not interested in using pthread. I want to use `clone`, and I have a reliably working `futex` wrapper. My only problem is that I cannot find information as to what to do with `errno`.

Comment: It is a system specific implementation detail. Study Linux [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) and look inside the source of the kernel, and of some libc, like [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/); you'll need to write some assembler code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [glibc source code](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/errno.c;h=dbdcb4356d2ac380606e78fd557e696d0b21a31d;hb=HEAD), `errno` is defined as a thread-local variable. Unfortunately, this requires significant C library support. Any threads created using `pthread_create()` will be made aware of thread-local variables. I would not even bother trying to get glibc to accept your foreign threads.

An alternative would be to use a different libc implementation that may allow you to extract some of its internal structures and manually set the thread control block if `errno` is part of it. This would be incredibly hacky and unreliable. I doubt you'll find anything like `__set_errno_location()`, but rather something like `__set_tcb()`.

```
#include <bits/some_hidden_file.h>

void init_errno(void)
{
    struct __tcb* tcb;

    /* allocate a dummy thread control block (malloc may set errno
     * so might have to store the tcb on stack or allocate it in the
     * parent) */
    tcb = malloc(sizeof(struct __tcb));

    /* initialize errno */
    tcb->errno = 0;

    /* set pointer to thread control block (x86) */
    arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, tcb);
}
```

This assumes that the `errno` macro expands to something like: `((struct __tcb*)__read_fs())->errno`.

Of course, there's always the option of implementing an extremely small subset of libc yourself. Or you could write your own implementation of the `write()` system call with a custom stub to handle `errno` and have it co-exist with the chosen libc implementation.

```
#define my_errno /* errno variable stored at some known location */

ssize_t my_write(int fd, const void* buf, size_t len)
{
    ssize_t ret;

    __asm__ (
        /* set system call number */
        /* set up parameters */
        /* make the call */
        /* retrieve return value in c variable */
    );

    if (ret >= -4096 && ret < 0) {
        my_errno = -ret;
        return -1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I don't remember the exact details of GCC inline assembly and the system call invocation details vary depending on platform.

Personally, I'd just implement a very small subset of libc, which would just consist of a little assembler and a few constants. This is remarkably simple with so much reference code available out there, although it may be overambitious.

Comment: I kind of feared it would turn out to be not all easy. You may be right that implementing my own wrapper around the one syscall (or maybe two) that I need is probably easiest.

Answer (score 0):

If errno is a thread local variable, so clone() will copy it in the new process's address space? i had overrode the errno_location() function like around 2001 to use an errno based on the pid.

http://tamtrajnana.blogspot.com/2012/03/thread-safety-of-errno-variable.html

since errno is now defined as "__thread int errno;" (see above comment) this explains how __thread types are handled: [Linux's thread local storage implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459692/linuxs-thread-local-storage-implementation)

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: It's both a comment and an answer.

Comment: Unluckily, that does not seem to be the case. It was something I had hoped for, however, a little test program that sets `errno` in the clone-child will also set it in the main thread. `errno_location()` outputs the same address from both parent and clone-child, too. So it is not "magically thread-local", you apparently need to do some unspecified/secret/internal setup (which presumably happens inside `pthread_create`). You said you _overrode_ `errno_location`, how did you do that? It's trivial on the application side (simple macro!), but how to override it for libc?

Comment: __erno_location() was defined as "weak" in the libc source. so it was as easy as line 104 here: `// WARNING: you MUST compile with -DREENTRANT for this to work
int *__errno_location (void) {
        long pid = (long) getpid();
        //if ( pid == s_pid ) return &g_errno;
        if ( pid <= (long)MAX_PID ) return &s_errnos[pid];
        s_bad++;
        s_badPid = pid;
        return &s_errno; 
}` But then they changed libc so that it was no longer a weak function and you couldn't do that any more. Then they added the __thread thread local variable type. are you using an old version of libc?

Comment: you're right. i have the same problem with the new glibc. maybe we do need to look at pthread_create() source code.

Comment: let me know if you find anything, because i am interested as well.